# How to disable automatic selection of the selected item in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox which works as directory selector. Visually its items are checkboxes, each checkbox is directory. User can check any of the checkboxes and this way make a selection of 2, 3, 10, you name it, directories.

This is the combobox binding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KnownDirectories}" 
  IsEditable="True"  IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Path=WorkingDirectory}">
```

It works.

What does not work is a case when user clicks not at the chekbox rectangle, but somewhere else, so it is the case when user actually selects the row, not switches the checkbox. In this case WPF selects the row, and sets its `ToString` representation (which is name of the type in this case) as `WorkingDirectory`.

As the effect, instead of something like "C:\my_dir" I see "DirectoryType".

How to disable this automatic selection when user selects (clicks) entire row instead of clicking on checkbox toggle?

*Temporarily I simply overrode `ToString` in my `DirectoryType`.*

Initial item template for combobox:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDirectorySelected}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=DirectoryName}" />
      </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

After Ash suggestion (all errors are mine):

```
<DataTemplate>
  <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsDirectorySelected}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=DirectoryName}" />
      </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
  </ComboBoxItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: bind `checkbox.IsChecked` to `ComboBoxItem.IsSelected`

Comment: @ASh, thank you, but it didn't change the behaviour, take a look at the updated question, I added the templates I used.

Comment: I think that instead of `<ComboBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsDirectorySelected}">` you should set that binding in ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle and remove ComboBoxItem  from DataTemplate

Comment: @Ash, but combobox is just one widget, if I set the binding at this level I will be no longer able to select multiple directories.

Comment: ItemContainerStyle is applied to each ComboBoxItem generated by ComboBox. ItemContainer is a ComboBoxItem, DataContext of ItemContainer == DataContext of ComboBoxItem